Expected Error Reduction for regression problems
I would like to implement in Python an active learning approach based on Expected Error Reduction (EER):
https://axon.cs.byu.edu/Dan/778/papers/Active%20Learning/roy.pdf
https://arxiv.org/abs/2211.09283
for a regression problem, where the machine learning model is a tree-based one (I'm planning to use XGBoost, a Random Forest Regressor or a VotingRegressor which simply averages the output of the XGBoost and Random Forest Regressor) . I don't have to use the Bayesian inference framework, but I'll use it if it's necessary. Currently, I have two issues:

the equations in the papers above are quite complicated and there's no pseudocode. I don't understand how to code up the loss function for EER, and what is the overall framework. My rough understanding is that in order to compute this loss, then, for each unlabeled input sample, I need to run my ML model, compute the probability under my ML model of each possible label, and then use it to compute the loss...but I'm missing the fine details.
The equations are given for the classification task. I actually have a regression task. How can I adapt EER to regression? I guess that I should replace sums over all possible label values with integration...since I can give upper and lower bounds for my output variables, Gauss-Legendre numerical integration would probably be the computationally more efficient approach.

How can I implement Active Learning based on EER for regression? An answer containing Python code/pseudocode would be the best, but even just a detailed explanation of the algorithm and the equations to use would be enough (I could then try to implement it myself in Python, asking a question on StackOverflow if I get stuck).

Very interesting question !!! Do you have any specific constraints on computational resources? For example, how feasible would it be for you to run Monte Carlo-based uncertainty estimations or ensemble methods? This would help tailor the computational efficiency of the solution. Also are there any specific consideration related to cost of labeling or potential distribution shifts in your dataset? For instance, are you concerned about outliers or extreme values in the regression targets that might affect error estimation? Addressing these might refine the sampling strategy for active learning

Oh one more thing, Is Mean Squared Error the primary error metric you're focusing on, or would you prefer to explore alternatives like Mean Absolute Error or a custom loss function? The choice of error metric could influence how to structure the Expected Error Reduction framework

@RobertLong 1) MC-based estimation: impossible with large sample size, may be possible with small sample sizes. I use tree-based methods, I don't know if it's possible to  get cheap uncertainty estimates with them. Could approaches such as the jackknife+ help in this respect? https://mapie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/theoretical_description_regression.html#id1 2) there could be some outliers, indeed.

@RobertLong I thought to use MSE since it's a commonly used loss function for regression, but I don't have a preference. I'd rather you define the framework in a loss-agnostic way - the user can pass a loss function, rather than having to work with a fixed one. Surely one could restrict the class of loss functions to those which 1) work with real variables, and 2) are differentiable almost everywhere. This class includes both MSE and MAE.

I agree that it’s sensible to keep the framework loss-agnostic, allowing users to pass any differentiable loss function that works with real-valued variables. . Jackknife+ is a great suggestion, and maybe jackknife+-after-bootstrap which might be better for for larger data.

@RobertLong sounds good. If you want to take a stab at writing an answer, I'll gladly read it

Yup, planning to have a go at it over the weekend when I should have sometime :) If you find it useful and you go on to implementation, and if it's something you'd like a collaborator on, then I would be quite keen to help - as I said initially, I think it's a really interesting project.

Background:
Active learning is a powerful tool for addressing the lack of labeled data, a common challenge in real-world machine learning. Supervised learning models typically rely on large, labeled datasets, but in many cases, obtaining labeled data is both expensive and time-consuming.
Active learning offers a solution by intelligently selecting the most informative samples to label, thereby maximising model performance with minimal annotation effort. This is especially important in fields like medical imaging or autonomous driving, where labeling can require domain-specific expertise. By focusing on the most critical examples, active learning significantly reduces the need for labeled data and improves the efficiency of machine learning models. In this context, Expected Error Reduction (EER) is a particularly effective criterion for guiding sample selection, as it seeks to maximise the reduction in generalisation error for each new label.
However, adapting EER to regression tasks is not without its unique challenges, especially in terms of computational efficiency and model uncertainty estimation. Addressing these challenges requires careful consideration of approximation methods and variance reduction techniques to make EER practical for large-scale regression problems.
Literature Review on Active Learning and Expected Error Reduction (EER)
This literature review focuses on the key research papers and findings related to Active Learning (AL), Expected Error Reduction (EER), and the application of these concepts to regression tasks using tree-based models such as Random Forest and XGBoost. This includes foundational works, modern advancements, and computational techniques designed to optimise the process, particularly for large datasets and continuous outputs.

Cai et al. (2014) - Cai and colleagues introduce an active learning method based on reinforcement learning to dynamically select the most informative samples. Although it targets multi-label classification, the principles of expected loss reduction and dynamic sampling strategies are applicable to regression tasks.

Key Insight: Offers insights into dynamic query selection strategies, applicable in regression-based EER implementations.


Fu et al. (2018) propose Approximated Error Reduction (AER) as an efficient alternative to traditional EER, especially in large-scale datasets. While designed for classification, the AER method can be adapted to continuous regression tasks by approximating the expected model change based on local sample neighborhoods. This offers a scalable approach when full EER computation becomes computationally prohibitive.

Key Insight: AER provides a scalable, approximation-based alternative to full EER calculation, reducing computational load for large datasets.


Huseljic et al. (2024) explore scalable active learning strategies using approximations of Fisher Information, enabling efficient sample selection in large-scale datasets. Although applied to classification, their methods for approximating error-based sample selection are applicable in regression-based EER when dealing with large datasets.

Key Insight: Provides scalable alternatives for selecting samples in large datasets, applicable to EER for regression when computational resources are limited. See the following section for further details


Kirsch et al. (2021) - This paper addresses active learning under distribution shifts and noisy data, suggesting robust uncertainty estimations for handling unrepresentative datasets. These strategies are particularly relevant when adapting EER to regression tasks in real-world scenarios where data may be noisy or suffer from distribution shifts.

Key Insight: Provides insights into handling noisy data and distribution shifts, which improves the robustness of EER-based regression models. Please see the following section for further details.


Kossen et al. (2022) - The authors propose surrogate models to efficiently evaluate models with fewer labeled data. Surrogate-based evaluation techniques can enhance the efficiency of EER in regression by reducing the computational costs associated with error estimation.

Key Insight: Helps improve efficiency in EER for regression through surrogate models and surrogate-based evaluations.


MAPIE (Jackknife+ Library) Documentation
MAPIE is a Python library designed to estimate Jackknife+ uncertainty intervals, which can be applied to regression tasks in EER. The pre-built functionality of MAPIE provides efficient ways to compute predictive intervals and estimate uncertainty in tree-based models, which reduces computational overhead.

Key Insight: Ensures efficient uncertainty estimation using Jackknife+, particularly when applying EER to regression.


Mussmann et al. (2022) - This paper expands on EER techniques by addressing the computational challenges of applying Monte Carlo methods to estimate uncertainty and error reduction. Mussmann et al. introduce techniques like Neural Control Variates (NCV) to reduce the variance of Monte Carlo simulations, which is particularly helpful for regression tasks with high-dimensional outputs.

Key Insight: Provides efficient Monte Carlo variance reduction strategies (e.g., NCV), which are incorporated into our framework for regression-based EER.


Park & Kim (2013) - The authors adapt the concept of Expected Model Change Maximization (EMCM) to regression. Their method for estimating how a new label impacts model parameters directly informs how to compute Expected Error Reduction (EER) in regression, especially with continuous outputs. The paper also highlights methods for robust outlier detection, which are critical for improving the resilience of EER to noisy data.

Key Insight: Provides robust strategies for handling outliers in regression-based EER, making it highly relevant for practical implementations.


Roy & McCallum (2001) - The authors lay the foundation for Expected Error Reduction (EER), focusing on classification tasks, but their approach is adaptable to regression problems by modifying error estimates. The paper provides a critical framework for selecting the most informative samples, which is extended in this solution to include continuous outputs and uncertainty estimation in regression models.

Key Insight:  This foundational framework is crucial for understanding EER and adapting it to continuous outcomes in regression tasks.


Scipy Documentation for Gaussian Quadrature
Scipy’s Gaussian Quadrature function is used for low-dimensional integrals in EER-based regression tasks, allowing efficient error reduction estimation when the output space is low-dimensional. In high-dimensional cases, this method is complemented by Monte Carlo sampling.

Key Insight: Provides efficient Gaussian Quadrature for low-dimensional integrals in regression-based EER.


Tan et al. (2023) - This paper introduces the Bayesian Estimate of Mean Proper Scores (BEMPS), which leverages proper scoring rules such as log probability and MSE to improve active learning strategies. The authors explore techniques to diversify query selection and improve model performance, even under noisy conditions.

Key Insight: BEMPS provides strategies for improving query selection in EER for regression, particularly by balancing uncertainty and expected error reduction. Please see the following section for further details.


Wan et al. (2020) present a comprehensive method for reducing the variance of Monte Carlo simulations via Constrained Neural Control Variates (CNCV). These techniques are particularly applicable when using Monte Carlo integration in regression-based EER, ensuring fast convergence of the estimator.

Key Insight: CNCV reduces variance in Monte Carlo estimates, significantly improving computational efficiency for EER in regression.




Steps in the Approach:

Uncertainty Estimation: Estimate how uncertain the model is about each unlabeled sample.
Expected Impact Estimation: Assess how much error reduction (e.g., mean squared error) the model would achieve by labeling that sample.
Expected Error Reduction (EER): Combine the uncertainty and potential impact to compute the expected error reduction for each sample.
Sample Selection: Select the sample with the highest expected error reduction.
Model Update: Retrain or update the model after adding the newly labeled sample to the training set.


I hope to address several important issues
1. Robustness to Outliers:
Park & Kim (2013) propose the Robust Expected Model Change Maximisation (REMCM), which enhances EER by incorporating local outlier probabilities to prevent selecting outliers during the active learning process​(Park and Kim, 2013). Outliers can severely degrade the model’s performance, and regression tasks are particularly sensitive to this issue.
Incorporation: We introduce a robust EER framework, which leverages outlier detection during uncertainty estimation and sample selection steps. This ensures that the most informative samples are selected without introducing noise into the model.
2. Variance Reduction via Monte Carlo Sampling:
Wan et al (2020) propose the use of Constrained Neural Control Variates (CNCV) to reduce the variance of Monte Carlo integration estimates​. High-variance estimates can lead to inefficient sampling and computational bottlenecks when calculating expected error reduction.
Incorporation: In the EER Calculation section, where Monte Carlo sampling is used to estimate integrals over possible output values, we introduce CNCV as a way to reduce variance in high-dimensional spaces. This ensures stable and computationally efficient estimates during the selection process.
3. Scalable Approximation of Error Reduction:
Fu et al. (2018) propose the Approximate Error Reduction (AER) approach, which provides a more scalable alternative to traditional EER by using hierarchical anchor graphs to approximate error. This is especially valuable when working with large datasets.
Incorporation: The AER method is integrated as an alternative to full EER calculation. In the Computational Efficiency Considerations section, we propose a strategy where AER is used when dealing with large datasets, providing a trade-off between computational efficiency and the precision of EER estimates. This allows users to adjust based on the dataset size and the computational resources available.
4. Balancing Uncertainty and Diversity:
Tan & Du (2023) introduce the Bayesian Estimate of Mean Proper Scores (BEMPS), which balances uncertainty and diversity during sample selection. Active learning strategies that rely solely on uncertainty can suffer from redundant sample selection, whereas diversity-based strategies mitigate this risk.
Incorporation: We incorporate BEMPS into the Sample Selection step, ensuring that selected samples are not only those with high uncertainty but also those that improve the diversity of the labeled dataset. This helps avoid the risk of overfitting to a narrow subset of the data, leading to better generalisation in regression tasks.
5. Efficient Approximations for Large Datasets:
Huseljic et al. (2024) propose methods to approximate the Fisher Information Matrix (FIM) in a scalable way for large-scale datasets​. Although originally applied to classification, these techniques can also be adapted for regression to reduce the computational burden.
Incorporation: The approximations for large datasets are introduced into the Computational Efficiency Considerations section, suggesting that similar techniques be used to approximate error reduction in high-dimensional settings. This reduces the time complexity of the algorithm without sacrificing too much accuracy.
6. Handling Distribution Shifts and Noisy Data:
Kirsch et al. (2023) propose the Expected Predictive Information Gain (EPIG) method to handle distribution shifts and noisy data. Their approach prevents the active learner from selecting irrelevant or noisy samples, which is critical for improving generalisation performance, especially in real-world regression tasks where the data distribution may shift over time.
Incorporation: In the Sample Selection step, EPIG is incorporated to handle situations where the data pool may contain noisy or out-of-distribution samples. This method ensures that samples are selected based on their relevance to the test distribution, improving generalisation and reducing noise in the labeled dataset.
7. Ensuring Long-term Reusability of Queried Data:
Hahn et al. (2024) propose General Reusability (GR), ensuring that selected data points remain useful even if the model or data evolves over time​(Hahn_et_al_2024_General…). This concept is valuable for active learning systems that need to remain adaptable and resilient to changes in the data or model architecture.
Incorporation: In the Labeling and Model Retraining step, GR is introduced as a strategy to ensure that the data points selected for labeling maintain their utility across different models or data updates. This ensures that the labeled data remains relevant, reducing the need for repeated labeling in dynamic environments.

The Role of Multiple Imputation in Active Learning with EER for Regression
Multiple Imputation (MI) could be useful in a partially labeled dataset, but it is not the core strategy for an EER-based active learning approach. MI can be seen as an additional tool for estimating label uncertainty by simulating multiple plausible labels. Here are the key considerations:

Comparing Human Labels and Imputed Labels: MI can be used to compare the distribution of imputed labels to actual human-provided labels. If the imputed labels are close to the true labels, this could reduce the need for future human labeling, or it could provide insights into areas where the model is unsure and human labels are critical.

Label Distributions: MI could generate a distribution of potential labels based on the current model and known data, helping to estimate the confidence interval


Pseudocode for Active Learning Based on Expected Error Reduction (EER) for Regression
Initialise:
1.Start with labeled dataset $ D_L $ and unlabeled dataset $D_U$.
2.Train the initial model $ M $ using the labeled dataset $D_L$.
Active Learning Loop (Repeat until stopping criteria is met):
1. Uncertainty Estimation (Incorporating BEMPS and Outlier Handling):

For each sample $x \in D_U$, estimate the predictive uncertainty $u(x)$.
Use an ensemble method (e.g., Random Forest) or approximation techniques (e.g., Jackknife+) to assess variance or spread in the predictions.
Adjust the uncertainty estimate using the local outlier probability to handle outliers robustly.

2. Robust Expected Error Reduction (REMCM for Regression):

For each sample $x \in D_U$, compute the model change $\Delta M(x)$ based on the size of the gradient at the sample.
Adjust the model change using local outlier probability to reduce the impact of outliers.
Estimate the change in error (Mean Squared Error or user-defined loss function).
If the output space is continuous, use numerical integration (e.g., Gaussian quadrature) or Approximate Error Reduction (Fu et al., 2018) for error estimation.
For high-dimensional output spaces, consider Monte Carlo sampling with Constrained Neural Control Variates (Wan et al., 2020) to reduce variance.

3. Sample Selection (Incorporating BEMPS and EPIG):

Combine the uncertainty $u(x)$ and model change $\Delta M(x)$ to calculate the Expected Error Reduction $R(x)$:
$$
  R(x) = u(x) \times \Delta M(x)
  $$
Select the sample $x^* \in D_U$ with the highest Expected Error Reduction $R(x)$ while balancing uncertainty and diversity (Tan & Du, 2023).
Use EPIG (Kirsch et al., 2023) to handle noisy data and distribution shifts.

4. Model Update (Ensuring General Reusability):

Request the label $y^*$ for the selected sample $x^*$ from the oracle.
Add $(x^*, y^*)$ to the labeled dataset $D_L$.
Retrain or incrementally update the model $M$ using the updated labeled dataset $D_L$, ensuring that the selected data remains useful for future models (Hahn et al., 2024).

5. Stopping Criteria

Stop if the maximum number of iterations is reached, if the model performance reaches a target threshold, or if the confidence level in uncertainty estimates becomes satisfactory.

Supporting Functions:

Uncertainty Estimation:

Input: Model (M), sample (x)
Output: Uncertainty estimate (u(x))

procedure estimate_uncertainty(M, x):
    predictions_list = []
    for each ensemble member M_i in ensemble:
        prediction = M_i.predict(x)
        Add prediction to predictions_list
    u(x) = variance(predictions_list)
    return u(x)


Potential Impact Estimation:

This function estimates the impact on the model's error by adding a sample to the labeled dataset and measuring the change in the model’s loss.
Input: Model (M), sample (x), labeled dataset (D_L)
Output: Estimated error reduction (Delta_L(x))

procedure estimate_impact(M, x, D_L):
    1. M_s = copy(M)  # Create a surrogate model
    2. Add (x, predicted_label) to D_L  # Simulate labeling the sample
    3. Train surrogate model M_s with updated D_L
    4. Compute loss before adding the sample:
       Loss_before = compute_loss(M, D_L)
    5. Compute loss after adding the sample:
       Loss_after = compute_loss(M_s, D_L)
    6. Estimate error reduction:
       Delta_L(x) = Loss_before - Loss_after
    7. Return Delta_L(x)


Expected Error Reduction Calculation:

Input: Uncertainty (u(x)), impact (Delta_L(x))
Output: Expected Error Reduction (R(x))

procedure compute_eer(u(x), Delta_L(x)):
    R(x) = u(x) * Delta_L(x)
    return R(x)


Sample Selection:

Input: List of EER values for all samples in (D_U)
Output: Sample (x_star) with the highest EER value

procedure select_sample(eer_values):
    x_star = argmax(eer_values)
    return x_star


Model Update:

Input: Model (M), labeled dataset (D_L), newly labeled sample (x_star) and its label (y_star)
Output: Updated model (M')

procedure update_model(M, D_L, x_star, y_star):
    Add (x_star, y_star) to D_L
    Retrain or update model M with new D_L
    return M'


Numerical Integration (if needed):

This estimates the change in loss over the range of possible output values, particularly important for regression problems.
Input: Model (M), sample (x), labeled dataset (D_L), number of samples (num_samples)
Output: Integrated error reduction over possible output values

procedure numerical_integration(M, x, D_L, num_samples):
    1. Initialize empty list integral_values = []
    2. for each sampled output y from predicted output distribution:
           a. Add (x, y) to D_L  # Simulate labeling
           b. Train surrogate model on updated D_L: 
              surrogate_model = simulate_model_update(M, D_L)
           c. Estimate the error reduction:
              Delta_L(y) = compute_loss_reduction(surrogate_model)
           d. Add Delta_L(y) to integral_values
    3. Compute the average error reduction:
       result = average(integral_values)
    4. Return result


Estimates Model Uncertainty

This function estimates the model’s uncertainty using ensemble methods.
Input: Model (M), sample (x)
Output: Uncertainty estimate (u(x))

procedure estimate_uncertainty(M, x):
    1. Initialize empty list predictions_list = []
    2. for each ensemble member M_i in ensemble:
           a. Predict the output for sample x:
              prediction = M_i.predict(x)
           b. Add prediction to predictions_list
    3. Estimate uncertainty as the variance of predictions:
       u(x) = variance(predictions_list)
    4. Return u(x)


Computes the Model's loss

This function computes the loss of the model, usually Mean Squared Error (MSE) or another user-defined loss function.
Input: Model (M), labeled dataset (D_L)
Output: Loss value

procedure compute_loss(M, D_L):
    1. Initialize loss_sum = 0
    2. for each (x, y) in D_L:
           a. Predict the output for sample x: 
              y_hat = M.predict(x)
           b. Compute the error: 
              error = y_hat - y
           c. Update loss: 
              loss_sum += error^2  # or another loss function
    3. Compute average loss:
       loss_value = loss_sum / len(D_L)
    4. Return loss_value


Notes for Efficiency:

Parallelisation: Use parallel computing for uncertainty estimation and impact calculation to handle large datasets efficiently.

Incremental Updates: Where possible, use incremental learning to avoid full retraining after each new labeled sample.

Subsampling: Subsample from the unlabeled pool $D_U$ to reduce computational cost per iteration.


Time Complexity
Disclaimer, I am not anywhere near an expert on deducing the time complexity of algorithms, please bear that in mind. I would be happy to be corrected if I have made mistakes.
1. Uncertainty Estimation

Ensemble Methods:

Time Complexity: $O(n \times k)$

n = number of samples in the unlabeled set

k = number of ensemble members (eg. trees in a Random Forest or models in an ensemble)

Why ?:  For each sample in the unlabeled set ($n$), you evaluate the ensemble of models to compute predictions. Since there are $k$
models in the ensemble, the total number of evaluations is proportional to $n \times k$. The complexity grows linearly with both the size of the ensemble and the number of samples.



Jackknife+:

Time Complexity} $O( n \times b)$

n = number of samples

k = number of bootstrap resamples

Why ?: Jackknife+ involves bootstrapping the dataset multiple times to estimate the prediction intervals. For each sample, you compute the resampled models and estimate uncertainty. Thus, the complexity is $O(n \times b)$




2. Model Change Estimation (REMCM for Regression)}

Time Complexity: $O(n \times d + n \times p)$

n = number of samples

d = dimensionality of input space

p = time to compute the gradient and update the model

Why ?: For each sample, we need to compute the gradient (which depends on the input dimensionality ($d$) and update the surrogate model. The complexity of the gradient computation depends on the input dimensionality, while the model update depends on $p$, the cost of training the model (eg. decision trees or ensemble). Thus, the overall complexity is $O(n \times d + n \times p)$


3. Expected Error Reduction (EER) Calculation

Monte Carlo Sampling:

Time Complexity: $ O(n * m) $

n = number of samples

m = number of Monte Carlo samples

Why: In Monte Carlo sampling, we generate multiple samples ($m$) to estimate the expected error reduction for each candidate sample ($n$). The complexity grows linearly with both the number of samples and the number of Monte Carlo iterations, making it $O(n \times m)$.



Gaussian Quadrature:

Time Complexity: $ O(n \times D) $

n = number of samples

m = number of quadrature points

Why: For each sample, we perform numerical integration using Gaussian quadrature, which evaluates the integrand at multiple quadrature points (D). The complexity scales linearly with the number of samples and quadrature points, making it $O(n \times D)$




4. Numerical Integration

Time Complexity: $O(n \times m)$

n = number of samples

m = number of integration points

Why ?: When using numerical integration, each sample requires $m$ integration points to estimate the integral over the output space. The total complexity scales with both the number of samples ($n$) and the number of integration points ($m$), leading to $O(n \times m)$


5. Sample Selection

Time Complexity: $O(n)$

n = number of unlabeled samples

Why: Sample selection involves choosing the sample with the highest Expected Error Reduction (EER) from the unlabeled set. This requires a simple linear search through the unlabeled set, leading to a time complexity of $O(n)$.


6. Model Update

Time Complexity: O(n)

n = number of labeled samples

Why ?: After selecting a new labeled sample, the model must be updated or retrained. If incremental learning is possible, the complexity depends on updating the model with the new labeled sample, which scales with the number of samples $n$. This leads to
$O(n)$ complexity.


7. Model Retraining

Time Complexity: $O(n \times p)$

n = number of labeled samples

p = training time for one iteration of the model

Why: If full retraining is required after each newly labeled sample, the time complexity scales with both $n$ and $p$. For tree-based models, training typically scales with both the dataset size and the number of trees (for Random Forest or XGBoost). Therefore, the complexity is $O(n \times p).


Overall Active Learning Loop:
The overall complexity of the Active Learning Loop depends on the combined complexities of the supporting functions. Each iteration involves estimating uncertainty, calculating the expected error reduction, selecting a sample, and updating the model. While some steps are more computationally intensive (eg. model change estimation, EER calculation), others (eg, sample selection) are relatively inexpensive. The number of iterations required depends on the stopping criteria, which could be based on a fixed number of samples or when the model's performance reaches a predefined threshold.
Conclusion
The proposed active learning framework, based on Expected Error Reduction, attempts to offer a robust and scalable approach for improving label efficiency in regression tasks. By integrating strategies such as Robust Expected Model Change Maximization (REMCM) for handling outliers, Approximate Error Reduction (AER) for scalable computation, and variance reduction techniques like Constrained Neural Control Variates (CNCV), this approach addresses the key challenges of uncertainty estimation and computational efficiency in large datasets.
Looking ahead, there is potential to further enhance this framework by incorporating techniques such as  Multiple Imputation (MI) and Variational Autoencoders (VAEs). While not part of the core strategy presented here, MI could be a useful tool for managing uncertainty in partially labeled datasets, simulating plausible labels, and reducing the need for human labeling. VAEs, with their ability to generate latent space representations, could be valuable for capturing uncertainty in the data and guiding sample selection in future extensions of this framework.
In summary, the current framework provides a solid foundation for active learning in regression, while MI and VAEs represent promising avenues for future research and development, potentially improving the framework's robustness and label efficiency even further.
References:
Cai, Q., Tao, R., Fang, X., Xie, X., & Liu, G. (2014). A deep reinforcement active learning method for multi-label image classification. SSRN. https://doi.org/10.2139/ssrn.4915522
Fu, W., Wang, M., Hao, S., & Wu, X. (2018, July). Scalable active learning by approximated error reduction. In Proceedings of the 24th ACM SIGKDD international conference on knowledge discovery & data mining (pp. 1396-1405). https://doi.org/10.1145/3219819.3220073
Hahn, P., Huseljic, D., Herde, M., & Sick, B. (2024). General Reusability: Ensuring Long-Term Benefits of Deep Active Learning.
https://www.activeml.net/ial2024/pdf/paper5.pdf
Huseljic, D., Hahn, P., Herde, M., Rauch, L., & Sick, B. (2024, August). Fast fishing: Approximating bait for efficient and scalable deep active image classification. In Joint European Conference on Machine Learning and Knowledge Discovery in Databases (pp. 280-296). https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-43823-4_19
Kirsch, A., van Amersfoort, J., & Gal, Y. (2021). Active learning under pool-set distribution shift and noisy data. https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.00079
Kossen, J., Mishra, P., Tschiatschek, S., & Spöttl, F. (2022). Active surrogate estimators: An active learning approach to label-efficient model evaluation.
https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.06315
Mussmann, S., Surana, M., & Ermon, S. (2022). Active learning with expected error reduction.
https://arxiv.org/abs/2211.09283
Park, C. & Kim, H. (2013). Robust expected model change for active learning in regression. IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence, 35(9), 2186-2197. https://doi.org/10.1109/TPAMI.2012.265
Roy, N., & McCallum, A. (2001). Toward optimal active learning through sampling estimation of error reduction. In Proceedings of the Eighteenth International Conference on Machine Learning (pp. 441-448).
Tan, W., Du, L., & Buntine, W. (2023). Bayesian estimate of mean proper scores for diversity-enhanced active learning. IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence.
Wan, Y., Cao, S., Wang, T., Song, L., & Tao, Y. (2020). Neural control variates for Monte Carlo variance reduction. In Proceedings of the 36th Conference on Uncertainty in Artificial Intelligence (pp. 186-195).

it looks good so far! You asked for feedback so here it is. 1) Adapting EER for Regression: whether to use Gauss quadrature or Monte Carlo simulation depends on whether the integrand is low-dimensional (then use GQ) or high-dimensional, in which case GQ is useless and you need to use MC. The second case is usually the norm in Machine Learning, but the issue is that the MC estimator can be crazy slow to converge is some cases and you need some way to reduce its variance, e.g. https://ecmlpkdd2019.org/downloads/paper/265.pdf.


Uncertainty estimation: both the techniques you mentioned seem relevant to me. 3) Hybrid Approach for Computational Efficiency: isn't it a bit early for this? I would first try to use Python libraries such as MAPIE (for the jackknife++ part) and https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quadrature.html for the Gaussian quadrature part (if you find that the integrand is actually low-dimensional). However, if you're a skilled C/C++/Rust coder, you may try this...it will make the code harder to use though (I'll need to compile it).


Thank you :) Regarding your points: 1) Yes, I agree with that, and thanks for the link to the Wan et al paper. 2) Good to know. 3) I have found through painful experiences that it's usually a good idea to think about computational efficiency from the start, but I take your point. Provided that the Python library used is calling fast compiled code to do the heavy lifting, then there is likely no point in trying to re-invent the wheel. I do have experience writing code in lower level languages (I was formally a C programmer then migrated to C++ and dabbled a bit with Rust fairly recently).......

.../Continued. One of the things I've been doing with the pseudocode is to try to figure out the time complexity of each procedure/routine which should help to inform the implementation details. So please leave it with me and I hope to have an update tomorrow..... I am housebound for the next couple of days due to the abominable weather where I live !!

Thanks for your help. Take your time, and I hope the weather will soon get better!

@DeltaIV I have just posted an update.  When set out doing this, I was expecting it to be quite hard, and I wasn't wrong ! I thought I was quite knowledgeable about AL, but it turns out that I wasn't much more than an advanced beginner ! But now I think I'm somewhere in between LOL :D
I hope it helps !!
